# Find duplicates of a specific file on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, duplicates

I have a directory that contains files and other directories. And I have one specific file where I know that there are duplicates of somewhere in the given directory tree.

How can I find these duplicates using Bash on macOS?

Basically, I'm looking for something like this (pseudo-code):

```
$ find-duplicates --of foo.txt --in ~/some/dir --recursive
```

I have seen that there are tools such as `fdupes`, but I'm neither interested in any duplicate files (only duplicates of a specific file) nor am I interested in duplicates anywhere on disk (only within the given directory or its subdirectories).

How do I do this?

Comment: define `duplicate` -- does that mean same file name, same md5 sum?

Comment: It means same md5 sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a solution compatible with **macOS** built-in shell utilities, try this instead:

```
find DIR -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5 -r | grep "$(md5 -q FILE)"
```

where:

- `DIR` is the directory you are interested in;
- `FILE` is the file (path) you are searching for *duplicates* of.

If you only need the duplicated files *paths*, then pipe thru this as well:

```
cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a specific filename, you could do:

```
find ~/some/dir -name foo.txt
```

which would return a list of all files with the name `foo.txt` in the directory.   If you're looking if there are multiple files in the directory with the same name, you could do:

```
  find ~/some/dir -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq -d
```

This will give you a list of files with duplicate names (you can then use `find` again to figure out where those live).

---- EDIT -----

If you're looking for identical files (with the same md5 sum), you could also do:

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort | uniq -d --check-chars=32
```

---  EDIT 2 ----

If your md5sum doesn't output the filename, you can use:

```
 find . -type f -exec echo -n "{} " \; -exec md5sum {} \; | awk {'print $2 $1'} | sort | uniq -d --check-chars=32
```

--- EDIT 3 ----

if you're looking for a file with a specific md5 sums:

```
sum=`md5sum foo.txt | cut -f1 -d " "`
find ~/some/dir -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | grep $sum
```

Comment: How do I specify the file name in the md5 case?

Comment: Are you asking `find ~/some/dir -name $(md5sum foo.txt)` ??

Comment: No, I'm looking for (md5-)identical files to one that I want to specify by name.

Comment: My md5sum utility outputs the filename right after the sum, though I understand that not all utilitites do that by default...  You may have to run `man md5sum` to check if yours can output it.  Outside of that, you can use a second `-exec` to find to print the filename after the sum...

Comment: @John BTW, thanks man... your answer enabled me to find a somewhat compatible solution on **macOS** as well. Upvoted bro!